# get_the_author() function redirects to home page - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to launch my own wordpress theme.

It's working fine with minor issue in development stage.

I use `<a href="" class="author_name fl_left">' . get_the_author() . '</a>` to print the author name link in my posts.

It's printing the proper author name.
But when I click it , it redirects to the home page.
why?

Is it necessary to create a author.php while we using a word press inbuilt function?

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Riffaz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you dont have authors page, then you can link user to authors post page. You can use this instead

`<a href="'.the_author_posts_link().'" class="author_name fl_left">' . get_the_author() . '</a>`

Comment: thanks for that fast response. I've made those changes. but still the same problem.

Comment: @ntexhi   
 
thanks for that fast response. I've made those changes. but still the same problem.

Comment: which code actually? I am using the following only code following code to print the author name? `print('<div class="author fr_right">
        <img src="/blog/wp-content/themes/3003Blog-1/images/serena.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="Serena" class="fl_left"/>
        <span class="posted_by fl_left">Posted by</span> 
        <a href="" class="author_name fl_left">' . get_the_author() . '</a>
         <!-- .author--></div> ');` do I have to create a author.php?

Comment: Why you are leaving your `href` attribute blank? Please check my answer again.

Comment: still same problem. 11print('<div class="author fr_right">
        <img src="/blog/wp-content/themes/3003Blog-1/images/serena.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="Serena" class="fl_left"/>
        <span class="posted_by fl_left">Posted by</span> 
        <a href="'.the_author_link().'" class="author_name fl_left">' . get_the_author() . '</a>
         <!-- .author--></div> ');

Comment: using firebug see what is the URL in href

Comment: when I use fire bug the href is just blank
`<a class="author_name fl_left" href="">3003admin</a>`

Comment: thanks for ur updated answer it's working.
this is also working `<a href="' . get_the_author() . '" class="author_name fl_left">' . get_the_author() . '</a>`
but when click the link it says page not found.
but I have an author.php
so why its causing?

Comment: yes,
So it seems your problem is solved, please close this question by accepting the answer